# Subscript out of Range VBA Printing

Tags: vba, range, out, subscript

I have a script that will print everything in my "Downloads" folder, the VBA script did work until I added a bit of code to "Fit Columns to Width" so that I could see all data before it printed, now it says "Subscript out of range" once it opens the first file in the "Downloads" folder, I think this is because the "Sheet1" is never called "Sheet1" it is instead named the first 15 characters of the actual file name.

Is anybody able to offer any assistance?

The Bit I've just added:
 `Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:H").AutoFit`

My Full Code:

```
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim FileName As String, Path As String
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Path = "C:\Users\Jonathan.mackell\Downloads\*.csv"

FileName = Dir(Path, vbNormal)
Do Until FileName = ""
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks.Open Left(Path, Len(Path) - 5) & FileName
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:H").AutoFit
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
ws.PrintOut
Next
wb.Close
FileName = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

set the `wb` variable when you open it instead of using activeworkbook, and include the `sh` variable instead of using activesheet, and put that in your loop, so you dont need to know the name.

```
Sub Test

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim FileName As String, Path As String

Path = "C:\Users\Jonathan.mackell\Downloads\*.csv"

FileName = Dir(Path, vbNormal)
Do Until FileName = ""
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Left(Path, Len(Path) - 5) & FileName)

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
  ws.Columns("A:H").AutoFit
  ws.PrintOut
Next
wb.Close
FileName = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```